# Permissions are too open after chmod 600

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, permissions

i'm new to linux. But I got stuck on connecting to aws server.

I know that I should change my mod to 600. But after doing so, I still get warning "permissions are too open"

[as you can see i only permit owner to w/r the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEFVr.png)

[but it still warn me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeHWx.png)

anyone konws how to solve this problem?

I actually set the right permissions but stil get refused to connect.

Comment: Normally key files live in their own directory (~/.ssh) which is also required to be 600. I would suggest putting it in another dir and chmodding that dir.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open